# Can't create EventHubs instance on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azureportal

I have created an EventHubs namespace. Now I would like to add an EventHubs instance within. On the Azure portal in spite of all validation success I keep getting the following error:

```
Operation name:
Create or Update EventHub

Error code:
BadRequest

Message:
Id in request does not match Id in payload. CorrelationId: <xxx>
```

Troubleshooting so far:

- Log out and log in to portal
- Close and restart browser
- Reboot PC
- Deleting browser cookies

No success, keep trying for 12 hours now. Any idea? Cheers!

**Edit**:
I got to the point where I deleted the namespace, created a new one. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to make it work, I had to delete the whole resource group an re-create it. Added EventHubs namespace again and the EventHubs instance to it, without any error.

IMHO it was a brutal way to solve it but ran out of ideas in the end. I would suggest raising a support ticket instead if you have it covered in your subscription.